# Pass PHP Variable/Class to Separate File

Tags: php, function, variables, activerecord, expressionengine

I hardly know any OOP PHP so I don't know how to properly pass variables.

I have a function that passes my results to a .php file that has the HTML table to show the results. I want to pass a variable "$config" to that file so I make a if/else statement.

Here is the function that passes my results to the file, that I need to pass the "$config" variable to create my if/else.

```
public function outputBrowser($results)
{
    // $rows = array();
    // print_r($results);
    // die();

    $config = $this ->config

    $this->EE->load->add_package_path($this->report_path);
    return $this->EE->load->view('output_browser', array("results" => $results), TRUE);

}
```

The main objective is to pass the selected drop down item to my file so I can output various HTML tables based on that selection. That selected value is in my config class or $config variable.

Comment: Shouldn't just adding the `$config` to the data(?) array work? `array("results" => $results, "config" => $config)`

Comment: does the view() function accept more parameters?

Comment: This really sounds like you should read more about how data exchange in web applications actually works. You will spent endless time otherwise by digging in the dark, guessing what might be going on and by trying millions of things all the time. Learn how things work instead and you will save a lot of time.

Comment: @AmazingDreams Thanks for the reply! Adding $config to the array worked!

Comment: I have refactored my comment into an answer. And heed the advice of @arkascha !

Comment: Duplicate/cross post: http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/12462/passing-variables

Answer (score 0):

As my comment seemed to have fixed it:

Just add the `$config` variable to the array you pass:

```
array("results" => $results, "config" => $config)
```